# How to enable openssl in RHEL for PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, redhat, php-7

When I try to install pear library, I got the following error.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: ext/openssl (ext/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/openssl.so (ext/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: ext/openssl (ext/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/openssl.so (ext/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/XML_Parser"
install failed
```

How to enable openssl?

In php.ini. I have extension=openssl uncommented.
But openssl.so file does not exist. Does openssl need to be downloaded and installed separately?

Answer (score 0):

This module might not exist:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/ | grep ssl
$ ls -la /usr/lib64/php/modules/ | grep ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

Youd don't need to uncomment extension in php.ini, extensions are load dynamicaly.

To check active extensions you can do :

```
php -me
```

If there is no openssl, then you need to install it. Checkout [rpmfind](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php-openssl(x86-64))

Comment: sudo rpm -ihv packagename.rpm